# 2000's Apocalyptic movie - man in a vault finds a butterfly?

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I remember the plot going something like this:

---

A society of people are living underground in a vault. After a while, when the main character (white, male) is instructed to go to a class or something, he wanders off into the vault and enters a dark room with lots of pipes in it. A butterfly flies into the room.

After the man discovers the butterfly, it makes him realize that there is life outside of the vault. He escapes the vault and sees the outside world for the very first time. (he never knew it existed, also I remember the setting being in a desert.)

The man finds a bar I think and I remember him getting into a fight with someone there.

---

This is as far as I can remember, not much but it's all I have. I'd appreciate any help though.. thank you

- Edit: It must have been between 2005-2010

Answer (score 20):

[The Island](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0399201/)

> A man living in a futuristic sterile colony begins to question his circumscribed existence when his friend is chosen to go to the Island, the last uncontaminated place on earth.

-

> - Lincoln discovers a live moth in a ventilation shaft, leading him to deduce the outside world is not really contaminated. Lincoln follows the moth to another section..
> - Lincoln and Jordan escape the facility, where they emerge in an Arizona desert.
>     [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Island_(2005_film))

And yes, they found a bar but the guards followed them, so they fought them before escaping.

Comment: They took some of the chase scene shots, added more CG, and reused them for Transformers.  It's a decent movie (certainly better than Transformers).

Comment: I think they did that because during the filming of Transformers one of the stuntman died, so they reused The Island footage

Comment: An both films shared the same director, Michael Bay

Comment: Oh, I think I remember watching this one.